# HTML5 canvas color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, colors

I have two blocks in HTML5 canvas.

1. Blue Block ie fixed in the canvas
2. Yellow Block that can be dragged with mouse.

When someone moves the yellow block over blue block, I want to change the color of overlapping or intersection regions to green. (please see attached image to have clear idea)

[image]

Since *blue + yellow = green*, is there any way to achieve this by changing the opacity level of blocks or I have to search for the overlapping area of the two blocks and display green block in that area or is there any other way?

I would like to know what is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: I think you can use rgba color and specify the opacity level to 0.5 each for example. That should do the magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [canvas globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html). The **lighter** composite type seems to fit what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 3 elements:

- Yellow bottom: Opacity 1
- Yellow top: Opacity 0.x, same dimensions as the bottom one
- Blue: Full opacity between the yellow divs

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cMhmY/)

This is far from done, but maybe a step in the right direction.

EDIT: I noticed too late that you requested it on canvas, but the principe should be the same there.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i couldn't achieve the desired effect using your technique.